# How does combining eldritch essence and shape with metamagic feats effect the spell level?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, warlock, eldritch-invocations

In the Complete Arcane, page 9, it indicates:

> When
> a warlock uses both kinds of invocations to alter an eldritch
> blast, the spell level equivalent is equal to the spell level of
> the eldritch blast, the level of the eldritch essence invocation, or the level of the blast shape invocation, whichever
> is higher.

Therefore if a warlock combines Eldritch Chain (Shape - 4th level) as well as Brimstone Blast (Essence - 3rd level), it will be as if casting a 4th level spell if I am understanding correctly since shape and essence levels don't stack together, and just take the whichever is higher.

Using Maximize spell-like ability on Eldritch blast requires CL to be at least 6 since, Eldritch blast is a 1st level spell and the formula is [(CL/2) - 2].

By that, can a 6th level warlock cast Eldritch Chain with Brimstone essence combined with Maximize spell like ability? Or do I need to re-calculate the spell according to maximize-spell like abilities formula, which would require CL 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You should re-calculate minimal caster level required

Eldritch Blast says the following about **its own** effective spell level:

> If you apply a blast shape or eldritch essence invocation to your eldritch blast, your **eldritch blast uses** the level equivalent of the shape or essence.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

Maximize spell-like ability checks effective spell level of an ability it affects, and applies at a time of using of a mentioned ability, so your now-effectively-fourth-level spell-like ability requires accordingly high caster level for this one particular usage.

Comment: Note that *Complete Arcane* has errata which affects (IIRC) how *eldritch blast*’s spell is calculated—I don’t **think** it changes this answer, but it would be good to double-check.

Comment: @KRyan Pre-errata it basically was blast's level, or essense's level, or shape's level, wichever is higher (CArc p. 9). So pre-errata the answer would be "You would never be able to apply maximize spell-like ability to your EB", because blast's level is allways CL/2 (allways higher than CL/2-2).